# Prove that there exists two integers $m, n$ such that $a^m + b^n \equiv 1 \mod{ab}$ with $(a,b) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there exists two integers $m, n$ such that $a^m + b^n \equiv 1 \pmod{ab}$ with $(a,b) = 1$.
Could you please give me some clues on how to solve this problem, not just show me the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Show that there is $m>0$ such that $a^m\equiv 1 [b]$. and $n>0$ such that $b^n\equiv 1 [a]$.
2. Let $c=a^m+b^n$. Show that $c\equiv1[b]$ and $c\equiv1[a]$. Deduce that $c\equiv1[ab]$

You need to use the fact that $(a,b)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

*Observation*: If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(a+b,ab)=1$.

(*Proof*: If prime $p$ divides $\gcd(a+b,ab)$ then, without loss of generality, $p$ divides $a$.  Since $p$ divides both $a$ and $a+b$, we know $p$ divides $b$, contradicting that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.)

Hence $$(a+b)^{\varphi(ab)} \equiv 1 \pmod {ab}$$ by [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).  And $$(a+b)^{\varphi(ab)} \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{\varphi(ab)} \binom{\varphi(ab)}{i} a^i b^{\varphi(ab)-i} \equiv a^{\varphi(ab)}+b^{\varphi(ab)} \pmod {ab}$$ by the [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), since $\varphi(ab) \geq 1$.

Comment: How does $\gcd(a+b,ab)=1$ when $(a,b)=1$ follow from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?!

Comment: [I was trying to give clues as per the OP's request.]  If prime $p$ divides $\gcd(a+b,ab)$ then, without loss of generality, $p$ divides $a$.  Since $p$ divides both $a$ and $a+b$, we know $p$ divides $b$, contradicting that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Well, I object to the way of phrasing it then because that doesn't follow from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. You only use FTA to guarantee the existence of $p$ that divides $\gcd(a+b,ab)$. But the theorem actually follows from the fact that if $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$ then $a \mid bx+cy$. When you said it follows from FTA I thought you wanted to write a prime factorization for $a$ and a prime factorization for $b$ which is a futile approach I guess because that doesn't give you any clues about $a+b$.

Comment: Happy now?  I think I'm going to avoid trying to "hint" and give "clues" in the future.  It's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @Rebecca That makes me sad, esp for questions where the OP wants to learn as opposed to demanding the immediate answer. You could make it obvious and follow the convention of stating __Hint:__.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution involving modular arithmetic:

$a^m\equiv 1 \text{ mod b} $, $b^n\equiv 0 \text{ mod b}\rightarrow b^n+a^m\equiv 1 \text{ mod b} $

$b^n\equiv 1 \text{ mod a} $, $a^m\equiv 0 \text{ mod a}\rightarrow b^n+a^m\equiv 1 \text{ mod a} $

Using the Chinese remainder theorem we can conclude $a^m+b^n\equiv 1 \text{ mod ab}$